# Swap Follow/Following button based on whether or not the user Follows the individual

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript, parse-platform, ionic2

I am trying to swap the Follow/Following button depending on whether or not the currentuser is following the other individual. In my code I have and NgIF set up and the thing i am having difficulty with is checking for the value in the array. If just one users name is in the the code works for that user. However if the array has multiple indexes the code turns the value to false.

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let pic of pics">
  <span *ngIf="pic.user!=current">
      <span *ngIf="pic.user!=cFollows"> 
        <button ion-button>Follow</button>
      </span>
      <span *ngIf="pic.user==cFollows">
        <button ion-button>Following</button>
    </span>
```

My TS File(all of the data in pics is in JSON:

```
pics = []
cFollows = ["user1","user2"]
```

So basically if the string value of pic.user is equal to any string in the array show the following button. If it is not show the follow button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured out i need to change the code to match below

```
  <span *ngIf="pic.user!=current">
     <span *ngIf="cFollows.indexOf(pic.user)==-1"> 
        <button ion-button>Follow</button>
      </span>
      <span *ngIf="cFollows.indexOf(pic.user)!=-1">
        <button ion-button>Following</button>
      </span>
  </span>
```